# Kivy 2.2.1 changed sizing of existing app

Tags: python, kivy

I just upgraded `kivy` to version 2.2.1. It caused my existing applications to suddenly become about 1/4 the size they were before. I've looked at the config file and there's nothing obviously different, and the release notes also don't appear to mention anything about this. I.e., the image below is how one of my apps looks now. Prior to this update it filled the area in the screenshot. Operating system is Windows 11. What could be causing this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with kivy 2.2 changing how dpi scaling is done. If by default, your Windows display is set to anything other than 100% you will encounter this problem. You can either reset your own machine to 100% or if you need this to work on other machines, try some of the solutions in this git:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8257

This worked for me:

```
        kivy.config.Config.set(
            'graphics', 'width', int(width / dp(1))
        )
        kivy.config.Config.set(
            'graphics', 'height', int(height / dp(1))
        )
        kivy.config.Config.write()
```